# Astro en Docker

Tags: docker

estoy creando un contenedor de docker del framework de Astro js en windows 10.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine3.15
RUN mkdir app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 24678
CMD ["npm","run","dev","--","--host"]
```

Construyo mi imagen con el siguiente comando

```
docker build . -t astro
```

Corro mi contenedor con este comando

```
docker run --name astro-container -p 24678:24678 -v D:\Workspace\Docker\Practicas\docker-astro-example:/app -v /app/node_modules/ astro
```

Hasta aqui sin problemas pero cuando hago un cambio en el documento index.astro no refresca la pagina para ver los cambios.

Espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Cuando creas la imágen Docker y haces cambios en el código fuente debes de volver a crear la imágen para ver los cambios.

Como alternativa puedes usar la [siguiente extensión](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers) de vscode.

Otra opción es crear un [bind mounth](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) para tener sincronizado tu código con los archivos de node.

También para recargar los cambios con node instala la dependencia de desarrollo nodemon.